# How to create a compressed JavaScript library for Jssor

Tags: javascript, jssor

I've done some changes to Jssor's JavaScript library 'jssor.slider.js'. After testing has been completed, I'd now like to create a new compressed 'jssor.slider.min.js'. Checking the available command line options of the compression tool 'Jssor.Compress.exe' I cannot see how to do this. An explicit command line call to do this would be great! Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the 'js' folder.

Use jssor.slider.min.compress.bat to compress jssor.slider.min.js

Use jssor.slider.mini.compress.bat to compress jssor.slider.mini.js

Or you can use jssor.compress.exe with specified option.

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-jssor-compress-exe.html

Comment: Hi jssor. Thanks for the fast reply. Works as expected. Obviously I've not checked out properly the provided Jssor tools. Using the Jssor tool leads to a smaller result than using the jscompress online tool. Thanks again - Mario

Answer (score 0):

You can use [minifier](https://github.com/fizker/minifier). Its a npm package.

The command is simple :

```
minify [--output path/to/put/file] path/to/file
```

Or you can use [jscompress](http://jscompress.com) which is a UI tool. It uses [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) which is also an open source library.

Comment: Hi vatsal. Thanks for the fast reply. I've used the jscompress online tool to compress the two JavaScript modules into one. Works as desired! Thanks again! Mario

Comment: Hi again. Though your suggestion works I've accepted jssor's reply as the correct answer, because it uses the compressor tool shipped with Jssor which leads to a smaller result. Unfortunately I cannot accept both answers! Kind regards and many thanks again - Mario.

Comment: Not a problem :) the right answer should be selected :)